# how to get the range date in vb6

Tags: date, vb6, datepicker, range

i have 2 date picker

```
Dim pday, eitday, otherday, tpenalty, difday, subpenalty As Integer
difday = Val(L1.Caption) - Val(L2.Caption)
pday = 7
eitday = 8
otherday = difday - eitday
tpenalty = 25
If difday <= pday Then
    PENALTY.Caption = 0
    ElseIf difday = eitday Then
    PENALTY.Caption = tpenalty
  ElseIf difday > eitday Then
  For i = 0 To otherday - 1
  subpenalty = subpenalty + 5
  Next i
    PENALTY.Caption = tpenalty + subpenalty
End If
```

the problem is when the month is change the calculation is invalid.

Comment: Have you tried using the DateDiff function?

Comment: no i didn't, i don't know it also

Comment: i just want to get the range date between the 2 datepicker can you help me?

Comment: i get i tnx datediff is great

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing based on your code (as many things are unclear), but this should give the number of days between two dates:

```
difday = DateDiff("d", StartDate, EndDate)
```

I've used `StartDate` and `EndDate` to signify the start and end of the lone period which are used to set `L1` and `L2`, as you shouldn't be converting from strings to dates for calculations.